# Cannot connect Robomongo using MongoDB docker image

Tags: mongodb, docker, robo3t

I am running mongo docker image that I pulled from [docker hub mongo image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/)

It works ok but when I start Robomongo I cannot connect to localhost. With following error message:

> Cannot connect to the MongoDB at localhost:27017.
>
> Error:
> Network is unreachable

I appreciate any help, thanks.

EDIT: I solved the issue by using the following command:

`docker run -p 27017:27017 --name mongo_instance_001 -d mongo`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Don't forget to map port to host port:

```
docker run --name some-mongo -p 27017:27017 -d mongo
```

Then

```
docker-machine ip
```

gives me `192.168.99.100`

Type in terminal

```
mongo 192.168.99.100
```

prints

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.4
connecting to: 192.168.99.100/test
Server has startup warnings: 
2016-08-22T07:35:20.214+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-08-22T07:35:20.214+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-08-22T07:35:20.214+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-08-22T07:35:20.214+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-08-22T07:35:20.214+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-08-22T07:35:20.214+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-08-22T07:35:20.214+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

I also tested with robomongo. I can connect without a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess figured out it with the same moment you helped :)

Comment: @zabware: Am getting an error on command docker-machine ip. Error: No machine name(s) specified and no "default" machine exists

Comment: @AnoojKrishnanG sounds like you have no machine running

Comment: @thanks a lot, you save me another 5 hours of troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

you can find docker-machine ip just typing this command
docker inspect

[container id is sha256](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMBFg.png)